# How do I add a part of a Url as as first search param?

Tags: javascript, url, parameters, slice

This is my setup

```
<script>

   $(document).ready(function() {
        document.querySelectorAll(".money").forEach(function(e) {
            e.addEventListener("click", function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    myfunction();
                }, 300);
            });
        });
    });

function myfunction() {
      var urlParams = window.location.search;
      var typ = "produkttyp=Tasting";
      var urlParamsUpdate = typ.slice(0,-3)+  urlParams + typ.slice(-1);
      var newUrl = "/collections/alle/" + urlParamsUpdate;
      
     
                window.location.href = newUrl.slice(0, -2) + "0%2C" + newUrl.slice(-2);
}

</script>
```

The result is the following url:
produkttyp=Tast?kategorie=Rotwein&money=10%2C0g

But thats not the result i am looking for. The wanted result is:
?produkttyp=Tasting&kategorie=Rotwein&money=0%2C25

So bascially I just want the ?produkttyp=Tasting& as the first search parameter, but its not working out. The mistake is somewhere here. I cant slice it the right way.

```
 var urlParamsUpdate = typ.slice(0,-3)+  urlParams + typ.slice(-1);
```

Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

```
<script>

   $(document).ready(function() {
        document.querySelectorAll(".money").forEach(function(e) {
            e.addEventListener("click", function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    myfunction();
                }, 300);
            });
        });
    });

function myfunction() {
      var urlParams = window.location.search;
      const urlParamsUpdate = urlParams.slice(1);
      const urlUpdateMoney = urlParamsUpdate.slice(0, -2) + "0%2C" + urlParamsUpdate.slice(-2);
      const url = "?produkttyp=tasting&";
 
      
     
window.location.href = "/pages/..." + url + urlUpdateMoney ;
}

</script>
```

Now I am just slicing away the "?" from the urlParams and then insert the missing part of the url "?produkttyp=tasting&" in the first place.